# Rails Administrate : how to change interface language

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n, administrate

I'm using Thoughtbot's Administrate library for the first time, everything is bright and shiny, but I can't find anything on the docs about translation.

From what I found in the changelog, the library is supposed to have several i18n translations already usable, but I can't find how to change the locale of the interface. Or just yml files to integrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it : I had nothing to do.

If you run into the same pb, just set up your application locale like so :

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :fr
```

and restart your local server, the user interface is now in the new locale.

Sometimes, software is so well done that it makes you feel dumb...